# Saving btmon output

Tags: java, linux, save, raspberry-pi, bluez

This is my first post here, although I've been reading stuff here for quite some time :)

I'm currently doing my bachelor thesis in computer science where we're doing an Indoors-positioning thing with iBeacons and Bluetooth. Where the device "being found" is currently a Raspberry Pi due to complications with smartphones.

I've got a bit of a problem with the btmon command on my Raspberry Pi. The full structure of our program is as follows:

1. Scan for bluetooth devices (iBeacons)
2. Save the output result    <---- Here's the problem
3. Filter the desired data
4. Send to server node

As this is a part of a program we're building, the commands are executed through Java code that executes the terminal command, and returns the output as a String. The method looks like this:

```
private String executeCommand(String command) {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\r\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();
}
```

I've got everything working when using another command (such as ifconfig) so the method works for ordinary commands, but I can't get it to work with btmon.
The full command I'm trying to run is this:

```
sudo btmon & sudo hcitool lescan
```

It seems to me as if btmon is running as a different process/runtime which would explain why the above Java code doesn't catch its output. I've been trying to "get" the btmon runtime but have failed to do so, and I've been trying to use ProcessBuilder with `inheritIO()` to change it's output source but couldn't get that to work either...

I've been googling this for a couple of days by now, and I've bumped into a couple of Python scripts that I can't get to work either (probably because I've never used Python before ^^).

So, in short: How do I save the output of `sudo btmon & sudo hcitool lescan`? Preferably to a String through Java code, but saving it as a file would also work!

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem and spent many days to solve this issue. The key point was `Thread` and not using `&`. Here is what I discovered:

- `&` literally runs in the background. Change `sudo btmon &` to `sudo btmon`
- Use Thread.

  - Thread 1 - start btmon (You can get result this Thread)
  - Thread 2 - start hcitool lescan

(btmon should first - because "lescan" occur hci events so btmon can get them) Summary - do not use `&` and use independent thread.